# MongoDB - how to filter data in the aggregate query when there is an array instead of string and I can't use it in match method?

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregate, pymongo

I am working with pymongo library in python. I need to extract the information that I provided in the below query. But I need to filter it in they way that I want to extract only informations where 
`results.informations.properties.Selector == 'technicalKey'`. Can you help me how to do that ? I tried to apply this in the match but I get `TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str`

```
db.collection.aggregate([    
    {'$match': {'jobId': {'$eq': 'asd0f23dsd'} } },
    {
        '$unwind': {
            'path': '$results.informations',
            'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': True
        }
    },
    {
     "$group": {
        "_id": {
        'country' : {'$ifNull': [ {'$arrayElemAt': ['$results.informations.country.Name',0] },None]},
            'selector': {'$arrayElemAt': ['$results.informations.properties.Selector',0]},
          'bugLevel': '$results.informations.bugLevel',  
        },
        "count": {"$sum": 1 }
     }
   },
] 
)
```

I tried to write it that way but it doesn't work.

```
db.collection.aggregate([    
    {'$match': { '$and': [ { 'jobId': { '$eq': 'asd0f23dsd'} }, { '$results.informations.properties.Selector': {'$eq': 'technicalKey'} }]} },
    {
        '$unwind': {
            'path': '$results.informations',
            'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': True
        }
    },
    {
     "$group": {
        "_id": {
        'country' : {'$ifNull': [ {'$arrayElemAt': ['$results.informations.country.Name',0] },None]},
            'selector': {'$arrayElemAt': ['$results.informations.properties.Selector',0]},
          'bugLevel': '$results.informations.bugLevel',  
        },
        "count": {"$sum": 1 }
     }
   },
] 
)
```

Guys, can you help me with that?

Comment: Update this question with sample docs & required o/p

Comment: You should provide with minimum input/output.